# Am I required to use a content stream to read the POST body content from a SolrQueryRequest?

Tags: java, solr

According to the solr documentation [here](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/content-streams.html), "the full POST body is parsed as parameters and included in the Solr parameters." Is this a false statement or am I missing something?

I have a Java class that extends the RequestHandlerBase like so:

```
... Imports ...
public class CustomRequestHandler extends RequestHandlerBase {
    @Override
    public void init(NamedList args) {
        super.init(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleRequestBody(SolrQueryRequest req, SolrQueryResponse rsp)
            throws Exception {

        SolrParams params = req.getParams();
        rsp.add("params", params);
    }

    ... Additional Overrides ....
}
```

In my solrconfig, I added a request handler:

```
<requestHandler name="/test" class="org.apache.solr.handler.ext.CustomRequestHandler"></requestHandler>
```

I then tested the handler using curl:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'http://localhost:8983/solr/testcore/test?test1=a' --data '{ "test2": "b" }'
```

The response I get back includes test1 but not test2. Using Wireshark, I verified that my request was a POST and that the content was correctly passed in.

I have tried tweaking the curl options (using different content-type headers, sending xml instead of json, etc.) but have had no luck. The only way I have found to retrieve the body content is by using the content streams.

Comment: I think its alluding to both GET and POST being parsed as being in the same format - i.e. `test1=a` sent as POST is the same as it being sent as GET. This is the regular format for POST data and is not JSON or XML.